# How can I get the value of a <td> from the clicked event of a previous <td> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="ui-widget-content">
        <a title="Edit" href="/Administration/Menus/Edit/001W"
           class="editLink ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"
            role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Edit</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="ui-widget-content">001W</td>
</tr>
```

To the editLink class I apply the following:

```
$('.editLink')
              .button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-clipboard"} })
              .removeClass('ui-button-text-icon-primary')
              .addClass('ui-button-icon-only')
              .click(function () {
                  editClick(this);
                  return false;
               });
```

Is there a way that I can make it so I call the editClick function with the value of the following `<td>` as a second argument?

So for example in this case it would be the same as calling editClick(this,"001W")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.

You can use `$(this).closest('td').next().text()` to do that.

See [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) in the jQuery documentation.

You could also use `$(this).parent().next().text()` if you can guarantee the DOM structure of the `td`'s, but I'd prefer the use of `closest()` to make it more versatile.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use $(#firsttd_id).next() only walks the DOM.

Comment: `next()` on it's own will not suffice here. There is no such element as `#firsttd_id` in the question.

Comment: that was just an example. #firsttd_id what your first td. you can replace it with $(this). common sense..

Comment: @Deepak If you put more efforts into your answers, surely everyone lacking common sense (including me) will understand.